# Visual Studio 2010 Express - bars near line numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm not familiar with all the fundamental parts of the VS, so this will be a rookie question.

[image]

I somehow made those rectangles appear near line numbers and I don't even know what they are called. So,

- How do I make them disappear?
- How do I make them appear?
- What are they called and used for?

*You may explain what they are used for if you feel like it, otherwise, providing the name will be sufficient for me to search my way through:)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These look like bookmarks in code. You can clear them by going to the Edit -> Bookmarks -> Clear bookmarks.

They are used for going to specific lines of code. Kind of like a bookmark in your web browser :)

Comment: As an additional note, if you have the Text Editor toolbar enabled, by default you'll get a bunch of button used to navigate using bookmarks.